# Vanilla JavaScript Carousel — How to Stop When There Are No More Slides

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to build a dead simple Carousel.

Each slide has a width of 25% — so a total of 4 are always displayed inside viewport.

So far I have: a slide left & right button, which increments / decrements `transform: translateX` by 25% on each click. This is to exactly move the first / or last slide on the list out of viewport, and make room for the next.

I can't wrap my head around how I can make the slider stop moving when there are no more slides.

I've calculated the total width of the slideList, and I’m thinking that I need to do something like:

“if total slideList width has moved past the left or right of the main container, disable slide button for that direction.”

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, that I always want there to be 4 slides inside the viewport. So as soon as the first or the last slideItem of the slideList is inside viewport, I want it to stop incrementing / decrementing 25%. Otherwise the slideList gets pushed out of the viewport.

```js
(function() {
 var slideList = document.querySelector(".slide-list");
 var slideItems = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-list li");
 var btnSlideLeft = document.querySelector(".btn-slide-left");
 var btnSlideRight = document.querySelector(".btn-slide-right");
 var numberOfSlides = slideItems.length;
 var totalSlideListWidth = slideList.getBoundingClientRect().width;
 var moveAmount = 25; // for translateX left / right
 var initial = 0;
 
 btnSlideLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  initial -= moveAmount;
  slideList.style.transform = "translateX(" + initial + "%)";
 });

 btnSlideRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  initial += moveAmount;
  document.querySelector(".slide-list").style.transform =
   "translateX(" + initial + "%)";
 });
})();
```

```css
.page-container {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.js-carousel {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1000px;
 font-size: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 150px;
 width: 25%;
}

.image {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.slide-nav {
 padding: 2rem;
 margin: 1rem auto;
 max-width: 150px;
}
.btn {
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
 border: 0;
 margin-left: .25rem;
 margin-right: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
 
 
 <div class="js-carousel">
   <ul class="slide-list">

    <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-park-iii--3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    
    <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-park-iii-wallpaper-17.jpg" alt=""></li>

    
     <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-park-iii--6.jpg" alt=""></li>   
        
     <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-world-wallpaper-7.jpg" alt=""></li>   
    
    
     <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-world-10.jpg" alt=""></li>       
       <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-world-wallpaper-10.jpg" alt=""></li>    
 
   </ul>

<div class="slide-nav">
 <button class="btn btn-slide-left">Left</button>
<button class="btn btn-slide-right">Right</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

There are many carousel examples on Github to look at, but I can't find one that is simple enough for my current JS skill level.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a variable to take count of the slide number, like (eg) `currentSlide`, when `btnSlideLeft` is cliked the slide number should increase, and with `btnSlideRight` should decrease. Next you can compare this number to the max number of slides (`slidesItems.length`) and the min (0) to hide or show the buttons. I changed a bit the code to show the basic idea and give you a start.

```js
(function() {
 var slideList = document.querySelector(".slide-list");
 var slideItems = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-list li");
 var btnSlideLeft = document.querySelector(".btn-slide-left");
 var btnSlideRight = document.querySelector(".btn-slide-right");
 var numberOfSlides = slideItems.length;
 var totalSlideListWidth = slideList.getBoundingClientRect().width;
 var moveAmount = 25; // for translateX left / right
 var initial = 0;
  var currentSlide = 0; // New
 
 btnSlideLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  initial -= moveAmount;
  slideList.style.transform = "translateX(" + initial + "%)";
    /* New */
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide == slideItems.length) {
      btnSlideLeft.style.display = "none";
    }
 });

 btnSlideRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  initial += moveAmount;
  document.querySelector(".slide-list").style.transform =
   "translateX(" + initial + "%)";
      currentSlide--;
 });
})();
```

```css
.page-container {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.js-carousel {
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1000px;
 font-size: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 150px;
 width: 25%;
}

.image {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.slide-nav {
 padding: 2rem;
 margin: 1rem auto;
 max-width: 150px;
}
.btn {
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
 border: 0;
 margin-left: .25rem;
 margin-right: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
 
 
 <div class="js-carousel">
   <ul class="slide-list">

    <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-park-iii--3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    
    <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-park-iii-wallpaper-17.jpg" alt=""></li>

    
     <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-park-iii--6.jpg" alt=""></li>   
        
     <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-world-wallpaper-7.jpg" alt=""></li>   
    
    
     <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-world-10.jpg" alt=""></li>       
       <li><img class="image" src="https://wallscover.com/images/jurassic-world-wallpaper-10.jpg" alt=""></li>    
 
   </ul>

<div class="slide-nav">
 <button class="btn btn-slide-left">Left</button>
<button class="btn btn-slide-right">Right</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank very much you, I understand your code and the disable btn feature is very useful. But my main problem is that the slider moves completely out of the window. I need a way to stop it, when the last slide has entered the window from the left or right (so there’s always 4 slides inside viewport). I probably phrased my original question wrong.

Is it wrong that I need to calculate total width of the entire slideList, and then find a way to detect when the entire slideList has moved past the edge of either left or right side of the window?